# How to generate links for sharing in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift

I want share url of product, product name to some user using either what's app or facebook etc.when user clicks on that product, same product page in app should be opened if app is installed. if app is not installed it should navigate to app store.Now how to generate that sharable link so that same page in app should be opened when user clicks?

Comment: https://medium.com/wolox-driving-innovation/ios-deep-linking-url-scheme-vs-universal-links-50abd3802f97

Comment: do you mean this : https://www.appcoda.com/working-url-schemes-ios/

Comment: You can do it with google shortener URL.

Comment: You can use [Firebase Dynamic Links](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/)

Answer (score 1):

To solve this issue you need to implement Universal link.

Add **applink:** in Target-> Capablities ->Associated Domain -> Domains -> Add server url

[image]

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([Any]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
    print("Continue User Activity called: ")
    if userActivity.activityType == NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb {
        let url = userActivity.webpageURL!
        print(url.absoluteString)
        //handle url and open whatever page you want to open.
    }
    return true
}
```

See the following post for more information
https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/universal-links-in-ios-79c4ee038272

Comment: How to handle url sir

Comment: you can handle url in 'restorationHandler' method in app delegate file, When you open application using tap on Universal link at that time call restorationHandler method.